# JavaFX inline CSS :pressed

Tags: java, css, javafx, inline

Here is an example of how I was able to change the :pressed to a dynamic image.

## CSS

```
.toggle-button_playerlist {
  -fx-graphic: base-button-playerlist-pressed;
  -fx-focus-color: transparent;
  -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
  -fx-effect: null;
}
```

## Java Code

```java
String CSS_BUILDER = "-fx-focus-color: transparent;" +
                "-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;" +
                "-fx-effect: transparent;";
URL url = new URL(Path to image);
CSS_BUILDER = CSS_BUILDER + "base-button-playerlist-pressed: url('" + url.toURI()"');";
NODEBUTTON.setStyle(CSS_BUILDER);
```

Felt like I would share since it took me forever to do this. The reason I'm building the CSS in a string, in case I wanted to add more properties on the fly depending on certain conditions. The purpose was this so players can customize the application as they please.

Remember when using inline properties, you can't use underscores "_", base-button-playerlist_pressed would not work while base-button-playerlist-pressed does.

This is a Solution, not a question!

Comment: Is it question?

Comment: You should not be posting answers as questions...

Comment: To preface my comment: It is perfectly acceptable (and even encouraged) to answer your own question. But you still need to follow the rules of this site. In other words, your question should _be a question_ and then you post the solution _in an answer_. The question and answer should align with [ask] and [answer], respectively.